# How come the print lines in a loop don't print

Tags: java, printing

The code below outputs nothing. How do I fix it?

package ProblemSet2;

public class FigureDraw {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final int N = 5;
    for (int line = 1; line <= N; line++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <-16; i-=4)
        {
            System.out.print("/");
        }
        for (int i = 1; i>32; i=+1)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        for (int i =1; i<-1; i-=4)
        {
            System.out.print("\\");
        }
    }


}
```

}

Comment: None of the termination expression is valid after the initialization expression https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Your any of inner loop conditions never become TRUE.

Comment: It will never print anything, all the conditions written in for loop will never be satisfied, hence it never goes inside the for loop and execute the lines written inside for loop, for Example 
` for (int i = 1; i <-16; i-=4)
        {
            System.out.print("/");
        }`
when i is 1 it's always greater than -16 no point in going inside the loop and decreasing the value of i by 4.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop executes when a certain condition is true and stops executing when it is no longer true. Your outer loop's condition is true (1 is smaller or equal to 5). However, your other loops don't print because none of the conditions are true. Let's look at the inner loops' conditions one by one:

Loop one: does not execute because 1 is not smaller than -16.
Loop two: does not execute because 1 is not bigger than 32.
Loop three: does not execute because 1 is not smaller than -1.

Let's break up a for loop a bit.
The first part is `int i = 1;` This sets the integer i as 1.
The second part is `i<-16;` In other words, this means "As long as `i` is smaller than -16, run the following code." And the last part, `i-=4` means that every time the following code runs, subtract 4 from i.

However, none of your conditions are true, so the statements within don't execute.

Try doing this:

```
for(int i = 1; i > -16; i-=4) {
    //Your statements here.
 }
```

Again, statements in for loops will ONLY execute when the conditions are true.